# How to lock Google Sheet cell from myself?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a computed value in a cell and do not want it be changed.

How to lock it?

I tried protect but there is no way to uncheck myself under "Choose who can edit".

[image]

Comment: Could you possibly create it under a burner account, and then give your main account read access to it?

Comment: That's one work-around. But I am surprised that this is not a common feature...

Comment: allowing sheets to have no owner seems like a surefire way to get a lot of pissed off tech support calls/emails from people who did it accidentally

Answer (score 1):

*"I am surprised that this is not a common feature"*
Actually this is by design. The **owner canNOT be unchecked**.

As a workaround.

- Pass ownership to a different account.
- Log through that account.
- Open the sheet and go to `File`-->`Share`-->`Share with others.`
- Under `General access` choose `Restricted`
- Give yourself/email editor permissions.
- Still in that account protect the range and then uncheck yourself.
- Logout and this time login to your account.
- You are now completely restricted from editing the range.

Answer (score -2):

Bonkers.

Right-Click, Protect Cells, Right-Click, Unprotect cells. That's enough to protect against accidental editing.